# Cannot get ASP.NET/IIS to serve .js files with custom cache-control settings

Tags: asp.net, iis

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 app, I have used the `clientCache` web.config attribute to customize the caching behavior for static files.

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlCustom="private,max-age-300" setEtag="true" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This is working fine for .css and image files, but I'm noticing in my browser's dev tools that .js files are not getting the custom `cache-control` and `etag` headers that the other file types are getting.

[image]

In addition, I've tried adding a custom handler, but it hasn't had any effect from what I can tell.

```xml
<handlers>
  <add name="StaticHandler_js" verb="*" path="*.js" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Any ideas on how I can get ASP.NET/IIS to treat .js files the same way as other static files?

Comment: In my test, js file can get the custom cache-control and etag headers. It may be that the compression and bundling of asp.net makes the js file bundled with other js files, causing you to be unable to see those header information. Could you please tell me how you reference the js file and show me the referenced code and js file name？

Comment: All of the ASP.NET MVC bundling and minification features are disabled. Internal assets are processed and minified at build time using Gulp and put into an output directory. Those output files are individually referenced the usual way, using `<script src='/foo.js'></script>` syntax.

Comment: @JacobStamm how are you loading your javascript files. Are you using BundleConfig?

Comment: I used your setting and it is adding the headers correctly for js files. Maybe you can use Failed Request Tracing to see if the response headers get written differently between your css and js files?

Comment: I hate to say this, but I'm not longer experiencing the issue and have no idea why. I tried every idea that was posted, but ultimately I removed them all and no longer have anything in my web.config that treats .js files any differently. I removed the handler from my original question, and the only remaining bit is the initial `clientCache` settings. Now it is handling the .js files just like the other file types like it's supposed to, as if the issue never existed. Wish I had a better answer as to why, but hey, it "just works" now.

Comment: Perhaps your js file was cached locally at the beginning and it has always been valid, so the browser did not cache the new from the server, resulting in the response header unchanged.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but I reset caching several times throughout my testing.

Comment: Yes. When you clear the cache on the browser, you need to get the js file from the server again. At this time, the js file has the cache header you defined. The good news is that your problem has been resolved and it does not reappear, so please mark the correct answer, which can help other people with similar problems.

Comment: I already addressed why I haven’t resolved the question in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>  
    <staticContent>  
      <clear/>  
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:01:00" />  
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpg"/>  
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/jpg"/>  
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>  
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>  
    </staticContent>  
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />  
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: @JacobStamm Can you see if this approach with mimeMap works for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm no longer able to reproduce the issue, so I can't say for sure whether or not this would work. I will note that the downside to this approach is that I have to figure out every type of static file extension that my project needs to be able to serve and add it to this list, which could end up being a very large list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by adding path-specific configuration to clear out all handlers and add only the static file defaults to those paths. This is an imperfect solution because it's based on the file path, not the file *type*, but because all of my JavaScript files are in this singular folder, it does the job.

```xml
<location path="Scripts">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If anyone has a better solution that doesn't rely on file path, I'll gladly accept that as the solution.